# Why is "Get good enough sleep and you make less mistakes if you're not deprived" not formal or correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

The words "good enough sleep" I was told is incorrect which I do not understand why it is incorrect and I also need to put in the word sleep before deprived.

It's a little confusing when I think I am using sleep as the context of the sentence and tried to make it less redundant but apparently that is wrong also which I also do not understand.

Comment: Some purists (and this is [controversial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/fewer-vs-less)) would say that 'less mistakes' should be 'fewer mistakes'.

Comment: This is also good to know I should make careful uses with less and fewer. Thank you for sharing this. @MichaelHarvey

Comment: I'm no purist, and I'd say it's barely controversial to assert "less mistakes" is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *deprived* can be used in a lot of senses. Even establishing a context doesn't make it automatically mean *sleep-deprived*.
In fact, having mentioned "good enough sleep", the later mention of *not deprived* makes the reader search for another sense of deprived that might apply.

Either of these versions would carry the meaning unambiguously:

Get good enough sleep, and you make less mistakes.

If you're not sleep-deprived, you make less mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I now have a better understanding when it comes to these kind of phrasing issues.

Comment: What's wrong with 'Get enough sleep, and you make fewer mistakes'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Nothing I can see. But I am a little sleepy...

Comment: But why is "good enough sleep" wrong to use while "enough sleep" is correct? @MichaelHarvey

Comment: I don't think "good enough sleep" is wrong. "Enough sleep" may convey the meaning, but many hours of fitful sleep (sleep that isn't good enough) may leave one sleep-deprived. A speaker or writer may wish to emphasize that. You might also say "Get enough good sleep and..."